# Can't watch database tables in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

**Someone has posted the same issue [*here*](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/support-requests/1219/), but there was no solution.**

First, I created a database called "authentication", then I tried to add a table called "users" into it.  There's about 9 columns in "users".
    Here's the result phpMyAdmin returned after I clicked "save the table" :
[image]

When I clicked the "Structure" tab, it returned:

[image]

**The report itself:**

```
{
"exception": {
    "mode": "onerror",
    "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of null",
    "stack": [
        {
            "line": 237,
            "func": "responseHandler",
            "context": [
                "     * @param object e Event data",
                "     *",
                "     * @return void",
                "     */",
                "    responseHandler: function (data) {",
                "        if (data.success) {",
                "            $table_clone = false;",
                "            PMA_ajaxRemoveMessage(AJAX.$msgbox);",
                "",
                "            if (data._redirect) {",
                "                PMA_ajaxShowMessage(data._redirect, false);"
            ],
            "filename": "ajax.js"
        }
    ],
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36",
    "uri": "sql.php?target="
},
"script_name": "sql.php",
"pma_version": "4.1.14",
"browser_name": "CHROME",
"browser_version": "34.0.1847.137",
"user_os": "Win",
"server_software": "Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12",
"user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36",
"locale": "zh_TW",
"configuration_storage": "disabled",
"php_version": "5.5.12",
"microhistory": {
    "pages": [
        {
            "hash": "sql.php?db=authentication&table=users&server=1&target=&token=ee222111c1b2c1e1b27850fed7dba5cb"
        }
    ],
    "current_index": "1"
}
```

}

Some properties here: 
**OS: Windows 8 

CMS: Wamp 2.5**
Apache : 2.4.9 
MySQL : 5.6.17 
PHP : 5.5.12 
PHPMyAdmin : 4.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem as you shown with the XAMPP 1.8.3 version.

And after I tried another version: XAMPP 1.8.2, this problem is solved.

So I recommend you to try XAMPP 1.8.2 version and see whether the problem is solved.

Thanks,
Jeff